# ImportError: No module named 'pygsheets'

Tags: python, pip, pygsheets

I installed `pygsheets` module with this command: `pip install https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/archive/master.zip`

When I tried to execute script, I got following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/bin/speedtest-to-google", line 7, in 
>       import pygsheets ImportError: No module named 'pygsheets'

I executed `pip list` and found: pygsheets (v1.1.2).

Comment: Are you using Python 3 by any chance and that `pip` is associated with Python 2?

Comment: @anon: Yes, script uses python3.

Comment: If you didn't change your Python installation or the pip symlink, then you should be using `pip3 install` to install packages for Python3

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script uses `Python3` packages, so command `pip3 install` has to be used.

Answer (score 3):

Use

`pip3 install` command to access it